# Typoscript: If page is not equal to

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to include a typoscript on the child pages of the page it's included on.

On page id 272 I have included in the setup a typoscript file:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/typoscript/fancyBoxPopup.ts">
```

And I only want this typoscript to run on that pages children.
So I tried this:

[globalVar = TSFE:id != 252, 253, 254, 270, 272, 271, 273, 274]

But that makes the script run on all children and parents (those listed in the statement)
Here is the full script:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id != 252, 253, 254, 270, 272, 271, 273, 274]
    page.includeJS >
    page.includeJS.ieFixes = fileadmin/templates/js/ieFixes.js

    columnWidth {
        page {
            main = 400
        }
    }
[end]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I manage to fix it.

I found **PIDupinRootline**.

So the final code looks like this:

```
[PIDupinRootline = 252,253,254,270,272,271,273,274]
    ...
[end]
```